# Excel formula for time

Tags: excel

Looking for formula to determine how many of the time given between 14:00 to 22:00

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0RZJ.png)

Comment: You can use the DATEDIF function to calculate the difference between two dates, check this link : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where have you gotten stuck? We're here to help with issues you run into, but not to do your work for you. Not showing your attempt will get you [downvoted](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). In your case, you could start with looking into [`Countif(`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) and [`Timevalue(`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/timevalue-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645)

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract both datetimes and you'll get the amount of days. If you want it to be in seconds, you just need to multiply this by the amount of seconds within one day (60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours), and obviously, don't forget to format your cell content as a simple number (the subtracting might cause a datetime formatting, which is not what you want).